# AJAX resulting in not consistently showing the right content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm doing a website and I want no URL change at all when navigating. So I'm using fully AJAX generated content.

Here's the link : http://nestecha.fr/confi/

So when you first arrive on the page it's all fine, but when you click on either "News" or "TV", it will :

- Sometimes work absolutely fine and generate all the content as I want it to.
- Sometimes not work at all, will generate content RANDOMLY, sometimes one row will load, sometimes it won't even be ordered in the right way, sometimes nothing will be loaded at all.

I can't see what's going on since it seems to be random. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Why is that ?

Thanks !

Here's some of the most important code that I believe is flawed :

```
// When we click on "News"
$('li a[href^=index]').on('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $sPage = '';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'webservice/newsShowReel.php',
            dataType: 'json'
        })
            .done(function (result) {
                $sPage += '<div class="container">';
                $sPage += '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 text-center title"><h1>Show Réel</h1></div></div>';
                $sPage += '<div class="row">';
                $sPage += '<section class="col-xs-12 text-center showreel">';
                $sPage += '<div class="view view-third">';
                $sPage += '<img src="'+ result['image'] +'" class="img-responsive">';
                $sPage += '<div class="mask">';
                $sPage += '<h2>'+ result['titre'] +'</h2>';
                $sPage += '<p>'+ result['description'] +'</p>';
                $sPage += '<a class="fancybox-media info" rel="group" href="'+ result['lien'] +'">Visionner</a>';
                $sPage += '</div>';
                $sPage += '</div>';
                $sPage += '</section>';
                $sPage += '</div>';
            });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'webservice/newsNouveautes.php',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
        .done(function(result) {
            $sPage += '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 text-center title"><h1>Nouveautés</h1></div></div>';
            $sPage += '<div class="row">';
            $sPage += '<div id="owl">';
            $.each(result, function(key, resultSingle) {
                $sPage += '<div class="item">';
                $sPage += '<div class="viewSmall view-thirdSmall">';
                $sPage += '<img src="'+ resultSingle['image'] +'" class="img-responsive">';
                $sPage += '<div class="maskSmall">';
                $sPage += '<h2>'+ resultSingle['titre'] +'</h2>';
                $sPage += '<p>'+ resultSingle['description'] +'</p>';
                $sPage += '<a class="fancybox-media info" rel="group" href="'+ resultSingle['lien'] +'">Visionner</a>';
                $sPage += '</div>';
                $sPage += '</div>';
                $sPage += '</div>';
            });
            $sPage += '</div>';
            $sPage += '</div>';
            $sPage += '</div>';
        });

    $('#page').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#page').html($sPage).fadeIn('slow');

        $("#owl").owlCarousel({

            autoPlay: false, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

            items : 4,
            itemsDesktop : [1199,4],
            itemsDesktopSmall : [990,2]

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show us some code - also bare in mind that the console is your best friend for things like this, try breakpoint sections and watch the console.

Comment: I didn't share any code because it's all AJAX, so everything is written in clear in folder js/jQuery.js. Didn't want to spam with too much code here :/ And as for PHP files, they simply send json informations and they're sending the right informations.

Comment: If we help you solve your problem, the link will point to working code. How is anyone reading this in the future supposed to understand the problem and see how this fixed it?

Comment: You don't have to post the whole thing, just enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Your general approach of hard-coding so much HTML into the AJAX response function seems like poor design. You should put the general HTML structure into the original page, and just hide the non-selected tabs. The AJAX success function can fill in the data as necessary. Perhaps consider using the jQuery UI Tabs plugin.

Comment: They might be sending the right information, but that still doesn't mean you shouldn't use the console to debug, I guarantee that if you debug through the console you'll see why the application is behaving in a weird way at times

Comment: Thanks a lot for comments. You're right I should post code, but I don't really know which code to post, since I'm not sure which part is flawed.
I have to code this much HTML into AJAX because every single page is like totally different from each other, which means I have to change the whole page via Javascript, right ?
Thanks against, I'll edit with the most important JS code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answser to my problem and why it's not working.

Originally, the code was this :

```
// When we click on "News"
$('li a[href^=index]').on('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $sPage = '';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'webservice/newsShowReel.php',
            dataType: 'json'
        })
            .done(function (result) {
                $sPage = '<div class="container">';
                $sPage += '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 text-center title"><h1>Show RÃ©el</h1></div></div>';
                $sPage += '<div class="row">';
                $sPage += '<section class="col-xs-12 text-center showreel">';
                $sPage += '<div class="view view-third">';
                $sPage += '<img src="'+ result['image'] +'" class="img-responsive">';
                $sPage += '<div class="mask">';
                $sPage += '<h2>'+ result['titre'] +'</h2>';
                $sPage += '<p>'+ result['description'] +'</p>';
                $sPage += '<a class="fancybox-media info" rel="group" href="'+ result['lien'] +'">Visionner</a>';
                $sPage += '</div>';
                $sPage += '</div>';
                $sPage += '</section>';
                $sPage += '</div>';
            });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'webservice/newsNouveautes.php',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
        .done(function(result) {
            $sPage += '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 text-center title"><h1>NouveautÃ©s</h1></div></div>';
            $sPage += '<div class="row">';
            $sPage += '<div id="owl">';
            $.each(result, function(key, resultSingle) {
                $sPage += '<div class="item">';
                $sPage += '<div class="viewSmall view-thirdSmall">';
                $sPage += '<img src="'+ resultSingle['image'] +'" class="img-responsive">';
                $sPage += '<div class="maskSmall">';
                $sPage += '<h2>'+ resultSingle['titre'] +'</h2>';
                $sPage += '<p>'+ resultSingle['description'] +'</p>';
                $sPage += '<a class="fancybox-media info" rel="group" href="'+ resultSingle['lien'] +'">Visionner</a>';
                $sPage += '</div>';
                $sPage += '</div>';
                $sPage += '</div>';
            });
            $sPage += '</div>';
            $sPage += '</div>';
            $sPage += '</div>';
        });

    $('#page').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#page').html($sPage).fadeIn('slow');

        $("#owl").owlCarousel({

            autoPlay: false, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

            items : 4,
            itemsDesktop : [1199,4],
            itemsDesktopSmall : [990,2]

        });
    });
});
```

The problem I had was not displaying the right content consistently. Also, the more AJAX requests there were, the more the display wasn't shown properly. 
The thing is, doing multiple AJAX requests at the same time gives bad results. So what I did was AJAX request once the request before was finished.

Here's the new code consistently working :

```
$('li a[href^=index]').on('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $sPage = '';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'webservice/newsShowReel.php',
            dataType: 'json'
        })
            .success(function (result) {
                $sPage = '<div class="container">';
                $sPage += '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 text-center title"><h1>Show Réel</h1></div></div>';
                $sPage += '<div class="row">';
                $sPage += '<section class="col-xs-12 text-center showreel">';
                $sPage += '<div class="view view-third">';
                $sPage += '<img src="'+ result['image'] +'" class="img-responsive">';
                $sPage += '<div class="mask">';
                $sPage += '<h2>'+ result['titre'] +'</h2>';
                $sPage += '<p>'+ result['description'] +'</p>';
                $sPage += '<a class="fancybox-media info" rel="group" href="'+ result['lien'] +'">Visionner</a>';
                $sPage += '</div>';
                $sPage += '</div>';
                $sPage += '</section>';
                $sPage += '</div>';

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'webservice/newsNouveautes.php',
                    dataType: 'json'
                })
                    .success(function(result) {
                        $sPage += '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 text-center title"><h1>Nouveautés</h1></div></div>';
                        $sPage += '<div class="row">';
                        $sPage += '<div id="owl">';
                        $.each(result, function(key, resultSingle) {
                            $sPage += '<div class="item">';
                            $sPage += '<div class="viewSmall view-thirdSmall">';
                            $sPage += '<img src="'+ resultSingle['image'] +'" class="img-responsive">';
                            $sPage += '<div class="maskSmall">';
                            $sPage += '<h2>'+ resultSingle['titre'] +'</h2>';
                            $sPage += '<p>'+ resultSingle['description'] +'</p>';
                            $sPage += '<a class="fancybox-media info" rel="group" href="'+ resultSingle['lien'] +'">Visionner</a>';
                            $sPage += '</div>';
                            $sPage += '</div>';
                            $sPage += '</div>';
                        });
                        $sPage += '</div>';
                        $sPage += '</div>';
                        $sPage += '</div>';
                    });
            });

    $('#page').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#page').html($sPage).fadeIn('slow');

        $("#owl").owlCarousel({

            autoPlay: false, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

            items : 4,
            itemsDesktop : [1199,4],
            itemsDesktopSmall : [990,2]

        });
    });
});
```